# Possible stack smashing?

Tags: c

I was looking at the following example in a book, and it seems to me that it will cause stack smashing:

```
int read_line(char str[], int n)
{
    int ch, i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
        if (i < n)
            str[i++] = ch;
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

If I pass it an array with room for 10 chars, and n = 10, the if-statement will be true up to and including 9, and `i` will be incremented to 10.
Then, it will write the `'\0'` character at `str[10]` which would be just past the end of the array?

It works just fine, though (tried building with gcc on Linux, clang on Mac and VS on Windows).
VS on Windows is the only one showing an error when running the program, even though I have tried setting -fstack-protector in e.g. clang.

Comment: Yes, off-by-one bugs are everywhere.  VS has a way to detect this bug with the /RTC compile option.

Comment: Your assessment is correct. Writing one past the end of the array is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), anything can happen, including working correctly. Using different compiler flags, different compiler, different system etc, may exhibit different behavior. Changing to `if (i < n-1)` should fix it.

Comment: The function is fine (could be improved by including `ch != EOF`) . The user just needs to use the function correctly.

Comment: @oda yes, indeed. But I could not find anything in the errata on the website.

Comment: So, I should just call the function with n set to one less than the length of the array?

Comment: In that case, as you say, the function is fine.
Still weird that only VS on Windows detected a write past the end of the array.
I will play with some more gcc and clang options...

Comment: It is entirely normal for an implementation not to "detect" such bugs, as there is no explicit checking.  `-fstack-protector` basically only tests if you have overwritten the return address.  If you merely overwrote another local variable, or slack space that was inserted for alignment, it won't be detected.  Try `-fsanitize=address` or `valgrind` for more robust (and much slower) checking.

Comment: While the function is technically not wrong if it documents that the buffer must be at least `n+1` bytes long, the more common idiom in C is that a size argument should correspond to the total length of the buffer.  So the function's design is confusing and likely to lead to bugs.

Comment: Oooh, I like -fsanitize=address:

  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 42) 'str' (line 16) <== Memory access at offset 42 overflows this variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assessment is correct, the code has undefined behavior if the user types `n` or more bytes before the newline.  There is also a problem if the end of file is encountered before the end of the line: the function will then run an infinite loop.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_line(char str[], int n) {
    int ch, i = 0;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        if (i + 1 < n)
            str[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        str[i < n ? i : n - 1] = '\0';
    }
    if (i == 0 && ch == EOF) {
        /* end of file: no input */
        return -1;
    } else {
        /* return the complete line length, excluding the newline */
        return i;
    }
}

int main() {
    char buf[50];
    int count = read_line(buf, sizeof buf);

    if (count < 0) {
        printf("Empty file\n");
    } else
    if (count >= sizeof buf) {
        printf("Line was truncated: %s\n", buf);
    } else {
        printf("Read %d bytes: %s\n", count, buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could this be made more efficient by exiting the loop if `i+1 == n`, e.g. `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' && (i+1 < n)) { ... }`?

Comment: @kmoser: this would be closer to the `fgets()` semantics (moving the `(i+1 < n)` test before reading the byte), but `read_line` as posted by the OP reads a full line from standard input and attempts to store the truncated contents to `str`, ignoring the rest of the input. The above implementation does not provide a way to detect truncation, a shortcoming that can easily be fixed.